# Utilização do "select" em sql (oracle), falha ao buscar

Tags: sql, oracle

Tenho que resolver a seguinte questão:

> 1.CONSULTAR EL NOMBRE (DESCRIPCION) DE LOS PRODUCTOS ADQUIRIDOS POR LOS CLIENTES HOOPS Y GOOD SPORT EN EL ANNO 1990.

o comando utilizado para a busca foi:

```
select p.DESCRIPTION 
from PRODUCT p, SALES_ORDER s, ITEM i, CUSTOMER c
where c.NAME = "HOOPS" 
  and s.ORDER_DATE like "%90" 
  and c.COSTUMER_ID = s.COSTUMER_ID 
  and s.ORDER_ID = i.ORDER_ID 
  and i.PRODUCT_ID = p.PRODUCT_ID;
```

E  me saiu o seguinte erro: ERRO na linha 1:

> ORA-00904: "S"."COSTUMER_ID": identificador invßlido

O diagrama utilizado foi testado e possui as FKs necessárias.

DIAGRAMA: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: SALES_ORDER não possui a coluna COSTUMER_ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select 
    p.DESCRIPTION 
from PRODUCT p
inner join ITEM i on i.PRODUCT_ID = p.PRODUCT_ID
inner join SALES_ORDER s on s.ORDER_ID = i.ORDER_ID 
inner join CUSTOMER c on c.COSTUMER_ID = s.COSTUMER_ID
where c.NAME = "HOOPS" 
and s.ORDER_DATE like "%90";
```